# Node express server, CORS API restriction, including an entry in my development machine’s hosts file

Tags: api, express, cors

I am trying to use an API that has an API CORS policy that does not support browser requests from any domain. In order to allow clientside JavaScript code to access the API, whilst developing my application, I have been advised to I serve my webapp from '*.thisCompany.com' domain.
It was advised to include an entry in my development machine’s hosts file, as follows, which I have done:

```
$ echo '127.0.0.1 localhost.thisCompany.com' >> /etc/hosts
```

Following this command when I run `sudo nano /private/etc/hosts`
 this is the screen that I see.

```
Host Database

localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost.thisCompany.com
```

And then I have been told that I should be able access my webapp at http://localhost.thisCompany.com.

I am using node express as my server and the code in my server.js file looks like this

```
var express = require('express');
var server = express();
var path = require('path');

var port = process.env.PORT || 'thisCompany.com';

server.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
server.use('/bower_components', express.static(__dirname + '/bower_components'));

  server.get('/', function(request, response) {
    response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/views/index.html'));
  });

  server.listen(port, function() {
    console.log("Node app is running at localhost:" + port)
  });
```

Can anyone advise what steps I should follow to enable me to call this API and bypass the API CORS policy?

I have read various other posts here, and also other articles online, however I cannot find the solution. Really hoping someone on this can help.

Thanks, Paul

Comment: Maybe I'm misreading the Express docs, but doesn't the first argument to `listen` need to be a port number? Currently it's the string `'thisCompany.com'` (unless `process.env.PORT` is set), which certainly isn't a TCP port.

Comment: You are right, I had it at 3000 and it worked fine, but as I wanted my express server to load 'http://localhost.thisCompany.com' this was one of my attempts at a solution, albeit a bad one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I misunderstood how I was supposed to view a page locally on my computer after amending the hosts file on my local machine. I didn't need to add anything to my express server. The express server code remained as follows:

```
var express = require('express');
var server = express();
var path = require('path');

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

server.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
server.use('/bower_components', express.static(__dirname + '/bower_components'));

  server.get('/', function(request, response) {
    response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/views/index.html'));
  });

  server.listen(port, function() {
    console.log("Node app is running at localhost:" + port)
  });
```

After adding the line mentioned in my original post to my hosts file on my local machine, I then needed to launch my server and access the page by following this link.

http://localhost.thisCompany.com:3000/

Although this is quite a niche issue, I hope this post helps someone in the future.